# System.speech dll errors

Tags: vb.net, speech-recognition

Okay so i'm totally new to this genre of programming (using speech recognition) and as much as I want to learn I tried searching for some sample codes and I stumbled upon this:

```
Imports System.Speech.Recognition
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Globalization
Public Class Form1
    ' recogniser & grammar
    Dim recog As New SpeechRecognizer
    Dim gram As Grammar
    ' events
    Public Event SpeechRecognized As  _
     EventHandler(Of SpeechRecognizedEventArgs)
    Public Event SpeechRecognitionRejected As  _
     EventHandler(Of SpeechRecognitionRejectedEventArgs)
    ' word list
    Dim wordlist As String() = New String() {"Yes", "No", "Maybe"}
    ' word recognised event
    Public Sub recevent(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
      ByVal e As RecognitionEventArgs)
        LabelYes.ForeColor = Color.LightGray
        LabelNo.ForeColor = Color.LightGray
        LabelMaybe.ForeColor = Color.LightGray
        If (e.Result.Text = "Yes") Then
            LabelYes.ForeColor = Color.Blue
        ElseIf (e.Result.Text = "No") Then
            LabelNo.ForeColor = Color.Blue
        ElseIf (e.Result.Text = "Maybe") Then
            LabelMaybe.ForeColor = Color.Blue
        End If
    End Sub
    ' recognition failed event
    Public Sub recfailevent(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
      ByVal e As RecognitionEventArgs)
        LabelYes.ForeColor = Color.LightGray
        LabelNo.ForeColor = Color.LightGray
        LabelMaybe.ForeColor = Color.LightGray
    End Sub
    ' form initialisation
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
      ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' need these to get British English rather than default US
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("en-GB")
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo("en-GB")
        ' convert the word list into a grammar
        Dim words As New Choices(wordlist)
        gram = New Grammar(New GrammarBuilder(words))
        recog.LoadGrammar(gram)
        ' add handlers for the recognition events
        AddHandler recog.SpeechRecognized, AddressOf Me.recevent
        AddHandler recog.SpeechRecognitionRejected, AddressOf Me.recfailevent
        ' enable the recogniser
        recog.Enabled = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

The thing is, it seem's okay. Altho i have a broken mic (the reason why I can't really test if it's working or not) but the immediate window is throwing me this lines:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Speech.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in System.Speech.dll
```

Any idea what are those? Am i missing a dll? or was there something that I needed too to proceed with this? Thanks in advance and more power!

Comment: `Altho i have a broken mic (the reason why I can't really test if it's working or not)` ...well this is not really a good setup for a speech recognition debug session.

Comment: Yep I know. The computer can "detect" the mic just that "it makes static sounds" and the thing that is really in question is the exception type thrown at me when I run the program. Unless their normal?

Comment: I cannot answer the question wether they're normal or not, but do note that the Immediate Window also lists handled exceptions, that is, exceptions that are caught by a `Try`/`Catch`-block meaning they don't necessarily break your code.

Comment: @VisualVincent ohh maybe that's the cause. I'll be having my mic tomorrow (gmt-8) and I really hope that it's not an error so I can start debugging and working out on the sample code above and work my way for my AI Project.